# type-mismatch in RDD function using java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to spark and I made some easy codes but I got the problem while doing the tasks. I am using Java 1.7 SE and Spark 2.0.1 to do some tasks.

Below are my codes.

```
JavaRDD<String> newLine = line.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
    public List<String> call(String s) throws Exception {
        List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> ls = Arrays.asList(s.split("\t"));

        String values = ls.get(ls.size()-1);
        List<String> value = Arrays.asList(values.split("\\|"));

        for(int i=0;i<value.size();++i){
            String ns = ls.get(0)+"\t"+ls.get(1)+"\t"+ls.get(2)+"\t"+ls.get(3)+"\t"+ls.get(4)+"\t"+ls.get(5);
            ns = ns + "\t" + value.get(i);
            ret.add(ns);
        }
        return ret;
    }
});
```

the error happened in `public List<String> call(String s) throws Exception` because of the `List<String>`. The error message showed that I tried to attempt use incompatible return type. I understood this message but I couldn't find the proper solution. In addition, this error just happened when I changed the spark library 2.0.1 from 1.6.0 using maven repo.
I appreciate it if you could give me the guidance on how to resolve this issues.

I attached the whole codes for the convenience as below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;

public class DataTrans {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String inputFile = args[0];
        String outputFile = args[1];

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Data Transformation")
                .set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").setMaster("local[*]");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        /* Load our input data. */
        JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile(inputFile);

        JavaRDD<String> line = input.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public Iterator<String> call(String s) throws Exception {
                return Arrays.asList(s.split("\n")).iterator();
            }
        });

        JavaRDD<String> newLine = line.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public List<String> call(String s) throws Exception {
                List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> ls = Arrays.asList(s.split("\t"));

                String values = ls.get(ls.size()-1);
                List<String> value = Arrays.asList(values.split("\\|"));

                for(int i=0;i<value.size();++i){
                    String ns = ls.get(0)+"\t"+ls.get(1)+"\t"+ls.get(2)+"\t"+ls.get(3)+"\t"+ls.get(4)+"\t"+ls.get(5);
                    ns = ns + "\t" + value.get(i);
                    ret.add(ns);
                }
                return ret;
            }
        });
        newLine.saveAsTextFile(outputFile);

        sc.stop();
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think it should return `Iterator<String>` not `List<String>` in `call()` return type.

Comment: Don't you need to add a return type to the flatmate function equal to the <code>call</code> method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should return `Iterator<String>` not `List<String>` in call() return type

```
   JavaRDD<String> newLine = line.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
        public Iterator<String> call(String s) throws Exception {
            List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> ls = Arrays.asList(s.split("\t"));

            String values = ls.get(ls.size()-1);
            List<String> value = Arrays.asList(values.split("\\|"));

            for(int i=0;i<value.size();++i){
                String ns = ls.get(0)+"\t"+ls.get(1)+"\t"+ls.get(2)+"\t"+ls.get(3)+"\t"+ls.get(4)+"\t"+ls.get(5);
                ns = ns + "\t" + value.get(i);
                ret.add(ns);
            }
            return ret.iterator();
        }
    });
```